# problems understanding an open source Blowfish API

Tags: c#, encryption, blowfish

process of encoding. its work

```
byte[] key = Form1.StrToByteArray("1234567812345678");//secret key
byte[] data = Form1.StrToByteArray("ololoololoololoololoololoololoololoololoololoololoololoololoaaas");//text for encoding


Blowfish bf = new Blowfish(key);//start class
bf.Encipher(data, 64);//64 is len string data
string encoded_text = BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();//take string and kill "-" and make to lower text
textBox1.Text = encoded_text;//result d211fb49d693f8f5bc3475b2ec6934a02d0951a052be4ff425d7dff0492fc502099b996453d8a008d211fb49d693f8f5bc3475b2ec6934a0a074812c17e7e19e
```

//begin method str to array

```
 public static byte[] StrToByteArray(string str)
 {
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            return encoding.GetBytes(str);
 }
```

//end method
//class blowfish begin

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace Kerberos
{
    public class Blowfish
    {
        const int N = 16;
        const int KEYBYTES = 8;

        static uint[] _P = 
        {
            0x243f6a88, 0x85a308d3, 0x13198a2e, 0x03707344, 0xa4093822, 0x299f31d0,
            0x082efa98, 0xec4e6c89, 0x452821e6, 0x38d01377, 0xbe5466cf, 0x34e90c6c,
            0xc0ac29b7, 0xc97c50dd, 0x3f84d5b5, 0xb5470917, 0x9216d5d9, 0x8979fb1b
        };
        static uint[,] _S = 
        {
            {
                0xd1310ba6, 0x98dfb5ac, 0x2ffd72db, 0xd01adfb7, 0xb8e1afed, 0x6a267e96,
                0xba7c9045, 0xf12c7f99, 0x24a19947, 0xb3916cf7, 0x0801f2e2, 0x858efc16,
                0x636920d8, 0x71574e69, 0xa458fea3, 0xf4933d7e, 0x0d95748f, 0x728eb658,
                0x718bcd58, 0x82154aee, 0x7b54a41d, 0xc25a59b5, 0x9c30d539, 0x2af26013,
                0xc5d1b023, 0x286085f0, 0xca417918, 0xb8db38ef, 0x8e79dcb0, 0x603a180e,
                0x6c9e0e8b, 0xb01e8a3e, 0xd71577c1, 0xbd314b27, 0x78af2fda, 0x55605c60,
                0xe65525f3, 0xaa55ab94, 0x57489862, 0x63e81440, 0x55ca396a, 0x2aab10b6,
                0xb4cc5c34, 0x1141e8ce, 0xa15486af, 0x7c72e993, 0xb3ee1411, 0x636fbc2a,
                0x2ba9c55d, 0x741831f6, 0xce5c3e16, 0x9b87931e, 0xafd6ba33, 0x6c24cf5c,
                0x7a325381, 0x28958677, 0x3b8f4898, 0x6b4bb9af, 0xc4bfe81b, 0x66282193,
                0x61d809cc, 0xfb21a991, 0x487cac60, 0x5dec8032, 0xef845d5d, 0xe98575b1,
                0xdc262302, 0xeb651b88, 0x23893e81, 0xd396acc5, 0x0f6d6ff3, 0x83f44239,
                0x2e0b4482, 0xa4842004, 0x69c8f04a, 0x9e1f9b5e, 0x21c66842, 0xf6e96c9a,
                0x670c9c61, 0xabd388f0, 0x6a51a0d2, 0xd8542f68, 0x960fa728, 0xab5133a3,
                0x6eef0b6c, 0x137a3be4, 0xba3bf050, 0x7efb2a98, 0xa1f1651d, 0x39af0176,
                0x66ca593e, 0x82430e88, 0x8cee8619, 0x456f9fb4, 0x7d84a5c3, 0x3b8b5ebe,
                0xe06f75d8, 0x85c12073, 0x401a449f, 0x56c16aa6, 0x4ed3aa62, 0x363f7706,
                0x1bfedf72, 0x429b023d, 0x37d0d724, 0xd00a1248, 0xdb0fead3, 0x49f1c09b,
                0x075372c9, 0x80991b7b, 0x25d479d8, 0xf6e8def7, 0xe3fe501a, 0xb6794c3b,
                0x976ce0bd, 0x04c006ba, 0xc1a94fb6, 0x409f60c4, 0x5e5c9ec2, 0x196a2463,
                0x68fb6faf, 0x3e6c53b5, 0x1339b2eb, 0x3b52ec6f, 0x6dfc511f, 0x9b30952c,
                0xcc814544, 0xaf5ebd09, 0xbee3d004, 0xde334afd, 0x660f2807, 0x192e4bb3,
                0xc0cba857, 0x45c8740f, 0xd20b5f39, 0xb9d3fbdb, 0x5579c0bd, 0x1a60320a,
                0xd6a100c6, 0x402c7279, 0x679f25fe, 0xfb1fa3cc, 0x8ea5e9f8, 0xdb3222f8,
                0x3c7516df, 0xfd616b15, 0x2f501ec8, 0xad0552ab, 0x323db5fa, 0xfd238760,
                0x53317b48, 0x3e00df82, 0x9e5c57bb, 0xca6f8ca0, 0x1a87562e, 0xdf1769db,
                0xd542a8f6, 0x287effc3, 0xac6732c6, 0x8c4f5573, 0x695b27b0, 0xbbca58c8,
                0xe1ffa35d, 0xb8f011a0, 0x10fa3d98, 0xfd2183b8, 0x4afcb56c, 0x2dd1d35b,
                0x9a53e479, 0xb6f84565, 0xd28e49bc, 0x4bfb9790, 0xe1ddf2da, 0xa4cb7e33,
                0x62fb1341, 0xcee4c6e8, 0xef20cada, 0x36774c01, 0xd07e9efe, 0x2bf11fb4,
                0x95dbda4d, 0xae909198, 0xeaad8e71, 0x6b93d5a0, 0xd08ed1d0, 0xafc725e0,
                0x8e3c5b2f, 0x8e7594b7, 0x8ff6e2fb, 0xf2122b64, 0x8888b812, 0x900df01c,
                0x4fad5ea0, 0x688fc31c, 0xd1cff191, 0xb3a8c1ad, 0x2f2f2218, 0xbe0e1777,
                0xea752dfe, 0x8b021fa1, 0xe5a0cc0f, 0xb56f74e8, 0x18acf3d6, 0xce89e299,
                0xb4a84fe0, 0xfd13e0b7, 0x7cc43b81, 0xd2ada8d9, 0x165fa266, 0x80957705,
                0x93cc7314, 0x211a1477, 0xe6ad2065, 0x77b5fa86, 0xc75442f5, 0xfb9d35cf,
                0xebcdaf0c, 0x7b3e89a0, 0xd6411bd3, 0xae1e7e49, 0x00250e2d, 0x2071b35e,
                0x226800bb, 0x57b8e0af, 0x2464369b, 0xf009b91e, 0x5563911d, 0x59dfa6aa,
                0x78c14389, 0xd95a537f, 0x207d5ba2, 0x02e5b9c5, 0x83260376, 0x6295cfa9,
                0x11c81968, 0x4e734a41, 0xb3472dca, 0x7b14a94a, 0x1b510052, 0x9a532915,
                0xd60f573f, 0xbc9bc6e4, 0x2b60a476, 0x81e67400, 0x08ba6fb5, 0x571be91f,
                0xf296ec6b, 0x2a0dd915, 0xb6636521, 0xe7b9f9b6, 0xff34052e, 0xc5855664,
                0x53b02d5d, 0xa99f8fa1, 0x08ba4799, 0x6e85076a
            },
            {
                0x4b7a70e9, 0xb5b32944, 0xdb75092e, 0xc4192623, 0xad6ea6b0, 0x49a7df7d,
                0x9cee60b8, 0x8fedb266, 0xecaa8c71, 0x699a17ff, 0x5664526c, 0xc2b19ee1,
                0x193602a5, 0x75094c29, 0xa0591340, 0xe4183a3e, 0x3f54989a, 0x5b429d65,
                0x6b8fe4d6, 0x99f73fd6, 0xa1d29c07, 0xefe830f5, 0x4d2d38e6, 0xf0255dc1,
                0x4cdd2086, 0x8470eb26, 0x6382e9c6, 0x021ecc5e, 0x09686b3f, 0x3ebaefc9,
                0x3c971814, 0x6b6a70a1, 0x687f3584, 0x52a0e286, 0xb79c5305, 0xaa500737,
                0x3e07841c, 0x7fdeae5c, 0x8e7d44ec, 0x5716f2b8, 0xb03ada37, 0xf0500c0d,
                0xf01c1f04, 0x0200b3ff, 0xae0cf51a, 0x3cb574b2, 0x25837a58, 0xdc0921bd,
                0xd19113f9, 0x7ca92ff6, 0x94324773, 0x22f54701, 0x3ae5e581, 0x37c2dadc,
                0xc8b57634, 0x9af3dda7, 0xa9446146, 0x0fd0030e, 0xecc8c73e, 0xa4751e41,
                0xe238cd99, 0x3bea0e2f, 0x3280bba1, 0x183eb331, 0x4e548b38, 0x4f6db908,
                0x6f420d03, 0xf60a04bf, 0x2cb81290, 0x24977c79, 0x5679b072, 0xbcaf89af,
                0xde9a771f, 0xd9930810, 0xb38bae12, 0xdccf3f2e, 0x5512721f, 0x2e6b7124,
                0x501adde6, 0x9f84cd87, 0x7a584718, 0x7408da17, 0xbc9f9abc, 0xe94b7d8c,
                0xec7aec3a, 0xdb851dfa, 0x63094366, 0xc464c3d2, 0xef1c1847, 0x3215d908,
                0xdd433b37, 0x24c2ba16, 0x12a14d43, 0x2a65c451, 0x50940002, 0x133ae4dd,
                0x71dff89e, 0x10314e55, 0x81ac77d6, 0x5f11199b, 0x043556f1, 0xd7a3c76b,
                0x3c11183b, 0x5924a509, 0xf28fe6ed, 0x97f1fbfa, 0x9ebabf2c, 0x1e153c6e,
                0x86e34570, 0xeae96fb1, 0x860e5e0a, 0x5a3e2ab3, 0x771fe71c, 0x4e3d06fa,
                0x2965dcb9, 0x99e71d0f, 0x803e89d6, 0x5266c825, 0x2e4cc978, 0x9c10b36a,
                0xc6150eba, 0x94e2ea78, 0xa5fc3c53, 0x1e0a2df4, 0xf2f74ea7, 0x361d2b3d,
                0x1939260f, 0x19c27960, 0x5223a708, 0xf71312b6, 0xebadfe6e, 0xeac31f66,
                0xe3bc4595, 0xa67bc883, 0xb17f37d1, 0x018cff28, 0xc332ddef, 0xbe6c5aa5,
                0x65582185, 0x68ab9802, 0xeecea50f, 0xdb2f953b, 0x2aef7dad, 0x5b6e2f84,
                0x1521b628, 0x29076170, 0xecdd4775, 0x619f1510, 0x13cca830, 0xeb61bd96,
                0x0334fe1e, 0xaa0363cf, 0xb5735c90, 0x4c70a239, 0xd59e9e0b, 0xcbaade14,
                0xeecc86bc, 0x60622ca7, 0x9cab5cab, 0xb2f3846e, 0x648b1eaf, 0x19bdf0ca,
                0xa02369b9, 0x655abb50, 0x40685a32, 0x3c2ab4b3, 0x319ee9d5, 0xc021b8f7,
                0x9b540b19, 0x875fa099, 0x95f7997e, 0x623d7da8, 0xf837889a, 0x97e32d77,
                0x11ed935f, 0x16681281, 0x0e358829, 0xc7e61fd6, 0x96dedfa1, 0x7858ba99,
                0x57f584a5, 0x1b227263, 0x9b83c3ff, 0x1ac24696, 0xcdb30aeb, 0x532e3054,
                0x8fd948e4, 0x6dbc3128, 0x58ebf2ef, 0x34c6ffea, 0xfe28ed61, 0xee7c3c73,
                0x5d4a14d9, 0xe864b7e3, 0x42105d14, 0x203e13e0, 0x45eee2b6, 0xa3aaabea,
                0xdb6c4f15, 0xfacb4fd0, 0xc742f442, 0xef6abbb5, 0x654f3b1d, 0x41cd2105,
                0xd81e799e, 0x86854dc7, 0xe44b476a, 0x3d816250, 0xcf62a1f2, 0x5b8d2646,
                0xfc8883a0, 0xc1c7b6a3, 0x7f1524c3, 0x69cb7492, 0x47848a0b, 0x5692b285,
                0x095bbf00, 0xad19489d, 0x1462b174, 0x23820e00, 0x58428d2a, 0x0c55f5ea,
                0x1dadf43e, 0x233f7061, 0x3372f092, 0x8d937e41, 0xd65fecf1, 0x6c223bdb,
                0x7cde3759, 0xcbee7460, 0x4085f2a7, 0xce77326e, 0xa6078084, 0x19f8509e,
                0xe8efd855, 0x61d99735, 0xa969a7aa, 0xc50c06c2, 0x5a04abfc, 0x800bcadc,
                0x9e447a2e, 0xc3453484, 0xfdd56705, 0x0e1e9ec9, 0xdb73dbd3, 0x105588cd,
                0x675fda79, 0xe3674340, 0xc5c43465, 0x713e38d8, 0x3d28f89e, 0xf16dff20,
                0x153e21e7, 0x8fb03d4a, 0xe6e39f2b, 0xdb83adf7
            },
            {
                0xe93d5a68, 0x948140f7, 0xf64c261c, 0x94692934, 0x411520f7, 0x7602d4f7,
                0xbcf46b2e, 0xd4a20068, 0xd4082471, 0x3320f46a, 0x43b7d4b7, 0x500061af,
                0x1e39f62e, 0x97244546, 0x14214f74, 0xbf8b8840, 0x4d95fc1d, 0x96b591af,
                0x70f4ddd3, 0x66a02f45, 0xbfbc09ec, 0x03bd9785, 0x7fac6dd0, 0x31cb8504,
                0x96eb27b3, 0x55fd3941, 0xda2547e6, 0xabca0a9a, 0x28507825, 0x530429f4,
                0x0a2c86da, 0xe9b66dfb, 0x68dc1462, 0xd7486900, 0x680ec0a4, 0x27a18dee,
                0x4f3ffea2, 0xe887ad8c, 0xb58ce006, 0x7af4d6b6, 0xaace1e7c, 0xd3375fec,
                0xce78a399, 0x406b2a42, 0x20fe9e35, 0xd9f385b9, 0xee39d7ab, 0x3b124e8b,
                0x1dc9faf7, 0x4b6d1856, 0x26a36631, 0xeae397b2, 0x3a6efa74, 0xdd5b4332,
                0x6841e7f7, 0xca7820fb, 0xfb0af54e, 0xd8feb397, 0x454056ac, 0xba489527,
                0x55533a3a, 0x20838d87, 0xfe6ba9b7, 0xd096954b, 0x55a867bc, 0xa1159a58,
                0xcca92963, 0x99e1db33, 0xa62a4a56, 0x3f3125f9, 0x5ef47e1c, 0x9029317c,
                0xfdf8e802, 0x04272f70, 0x80bb155c, 0x05282ce3, 0x95c11548, 0xe4c66d22,
                0x48c1133f, 0xc70f86dc, 0x07f9c9ee, 0x41041f0f, 0x404779a4, 0x5d886e17,
                0x325f51eb, 0xd59bc0d1, 0xf2bcc18f, 0x41113564, 0x257b7834, 0x602a9c60,
                0xdff8e8a3, 0x1f636c1b, 0x0e12b4c2, 0x02e1329e, 0xaf664fd1, 0xcad18115,
                0x6b2395e0, 0x333e92e1, 0x3b240b62, 0xeebeb922, 0x85b2a20e, 0xe6ba0d99,
                0xde720c8c, 0x2da2f728, 0xd0127845, 0x95b794fd, 0x647d0862, 0xe7ccf5f0,
                0x5449a36f, 0x877d48fa, 0xc39dfd27, 0xf33e8d1e, 0x0a476341, 0x992eff74,
                0x3a6f6eab, 0xf4f8fd37, 0xa812dc60, 0xa1ebddf8, 0x991be14c, 0xdb6e6b0d,
                0xc67b5510, 0x6d672c37, 0x2765d43b, 0xdcd0e804, 0xf1290dc7, 0xcc00ffa3,
                0xb5390f92, 0x690fed0b, 0x667b9ffb, 0xcedb7d9c, 0xa091cf0b, 0xd9155ea3,
                0xbb132f88, 0x515bad24, 0x7b9479bf, 0x763bd6eb, 0x37392eb3, 0xcc115979,
                0x8026e297, 0xf42e312d, 0x6842ada7, 0xc66a2b3b, 0x12754ccc, 0x782ef11c,
                0x6a124237, 0xb79251e7, 0x06a1bbe6, 0x4bfb6350, 0x1a6b1018, 0x11caedfa,
                0x3d25bdd8, 0xe2e1c3c9, 0x44421659, 0x0a121386, 0xd90cec6e, 0xd5abea2a,
                0x64af674e, 0xda86a85f, 0xbebfe988, 0x64e4c3fe, 0x9dbc8057, 0xf0f7c086,
                0x60787bf8, 0x6003604d, 0xd1fd8346, 0xf6381fb0, 0x7745ae04, 0xd736fccc,
                0x83426b33, 0xf01eab71, 0xb0804187, 0x3c005e5f, 0x77a057be, 0xbde8ae24,
                0x55464299, 0xbf582e61, 0x4e58f48f, 0xf2ddfda2, 0xf474ef38, 0x8789bdc2,
                0x5366f9c3, 0xc8b38e74, 0xb475f255, 0x46fcd9b9, 0x7aeb2661, 0x8b1ddf84,
                0x846a0e79, 0x915f95e2, 0x466e598e, 0x20b45770, 0x8cd55591, 0xc902de4c,
                0xb90bace1, 0xbb8205d0, 0x11a86248, 0x7574a99e, 0xb77f19b6, 0xe0a9dc09,
                0x662d09a1, 0xc4324633, 0xe85a1f02, 0x09f0be8c, 0x4a99a025, 0x1d6efe10,
                0x1ab93d1d, 0x0ba5a4df, 0xa186f20f, 0x2868f169, 0xdcb7da83, 0x573906fe,
                0xa1e2ce9b, 0x4fcd7f52, 0x50115e01, 0xa70683fa, 0xa002b5c4, 0x0de6d027,
                0x9af88c27, 0x773f8641, 0xc3604c06, 0x61a806b5, 0xf0177a28, 0xc0f586e0,
                0x006058aa, 0x30dc7d62, 0x11e69ed7, 0x2338ea63, 0x53c2dd94, 0xc2c21634,
                0xbbcbee56, 0x90bcb6de, 0xebfc7da1, 0xce591d76, 0x6f05e409, 0x4b7c0188,
                0x39720a3d, 0x7c927c24, 0x86e3725f, 0x724d9db9, 0x1ac15bb4, 0xd39eb8fc,
                0xed545578, 0x08fca5b5, 0xd83d7cd3, 0x4dad0fc4, 0x1e50ef5e, 0xb161e6f8,
                0xa28514d9, 0x6c51133c, 0x6fd5c7e7, 0x56e14ec4, 0x362abfce, 0xddc6c837,
                0xd79a3234, 0x92638212, 0x670efa8e, 0x406000e0
            },
            {
                0x3a39ce37, 0xd3faf5cf, 0xabc27737, 0x5ac52d1b, 0x5cb0679e, 0x4fa33742,
                0xd3822740, 0x99bc9bbe, 0xd5118e9d, 0xbf0f7315, 0xd62d1c7e, 0xc700c47b,
                0xb78c1b6b, 0x21a19045, 0xb26eb1be, 0x6a366eb4, 0x5748ab2f, 0xbc946e79,
                0xc6a376d2, 0x6549c2c8, 0x530ff8ee, 0x468dde7d, 0xd5730a1d, 0x4cd04dc6,
                0x2939bbdb, 0xa9ba4650, 0xac9526e8, 0xbe5ee304, 0xa1fad5f0, 0x6a2d519a,
                0x63ef8ce2, 0x9a86ee22, 0xc089c2b8, 0x43242ef6, 0xa51e03aa, 0x9cf2d0a4,
                0x83c061ba, 0x9be96a4d, 0x8fe51550, 0xba645bd6, 0x2826a2f9, 0xa73a3ae1,
                0x4ba99586, 0xef5562e9, 0xc72fefd3, 0xf752f7da, 0x3f046f69, 0x77fa0a59,
                0x80e4a915, 0x87b08601, 0x9b09e6ad, 0x3b3ee593, 0xe990fd5a, 0x9e34d797,
                0x2cf0b7d9, 0x022b8b51, 0x96d5ac3a, 0x017da67d, 0xd1cf3ed6, 0x7c7d2d28,
                0x1f9f25cf, 0xadf2b89b, 0x5ad6b472, 0x5a88f54c, 0xe029ac71, 0xe019a5e6,
                0x47b0acfd, 0xed93fa9b, 0xe8d3c48d, 0x283b57cc, 0xf8d56629, 0x79132e28,
                0x785f0191, 0xed756055, 0xf7960e44, 0xe3d35e8c, 0x15056dd4, 0x88f46dba,
                0x03a16125, 0x0564f0bd, 0xc3eb9e15, 0x3c9057a2, 0x97271aec, 0xa93a072a,
                0x1b3f6d9b, 0x1e6321f5, 0xf59c66fb, 0x26dcf319, 0x7533d928, 0xb155fdf5,
                0x03563482, 0x8aba3cbb, 0x28517711, 0xc20ad9f8, 0xabcc5167, 0xccad925f,
                0x4de81751, 0x3830dc8e, 0x379d5862, 0x9320f991, 0xea7a90c2, 0xfb3e7bce,
                0x5121ce64, 0x774fbe32, 0xa8b6e37e, 0xc3293d46, 0x48de5369, 0x6413e680,
                0xa2ae0810, 0xdd6db224, 0x69852dfd, 0x09072166, 0xb39a460a, 0x6445c0dd,
                0x586cdecf, 0x1c20c8ae, 0x5bbef7dd, 0x1b588d40, 0xccd2017f, 0x6bb4e3bb,
                0xdda26a7e, 0x3a59ff45, 0x3e350a44, 0xbcb4cdd5, 0x72eacea8, 0xfa6484bb,
                0x8d6612ae, 0xbf3c6f47, 0xd29be463, 0x542f5d9e, 0xaec2771b, 0xf64e6370,
                0x740e0d8d, 0xe75b1357, 0xf8721671, 0xaf537d5d, 0x4040cb08, 0x4eb4e2cc,
                0x34d2466a, 0x0115af84, 0xe1b00428, 0x95983a1d, 0x06b89fb4, 0xce6ea048,
                0x6f3f3b82, 0x3520ab82, 0x011a1d4b, 0x277227f8, 0x611560b1, 0xe7933fdc,
                0xbb3a792b, 0x344525bd, 0xa08839e1, 0x51ce794b, 0x2f32c9b7, 0xa01fbac9,
                0xe01cc87e, 0xbcc7d1f6, 0xcf0111c3, 0xa1e8aac7, 0x1a908749, 0xd44fbd9a,
                0xd0dadecb, 0xd50ada38, 0x0339c32a, 0xc6913667, 0x8df9317c, 0xe0b12b4f,
                0xf79e59b7, 0x43f5bb3a, 0xf2d519ff, 0x27d9459c, 0xbf97222c, 0x15e6fc2a,
                0x0f91fc71, 0x9b941525, 0xfae59361, 0xceb69ceb, 0xc2a86459, 0x12baa8d1,
                0xb6c1075e, 0xe3056a0c, 0x10d25065, 0xcb03a442, 0xe0ec6e0e, 0x1698db3b,
                0x4c98a0be, 0x3278e964, 0x9f1f9532, 0xe0d392df, 0xd3a0342b, 0x8971f21e,
                0x1b0a7441, 0x4ba3348c, 0xc5be7120, 0xc37632d8, 0xdf359f8d, 0x9b992f2e,
                0xe60b6f47, 0x0fe3f11d, 0xe54cda54, 0x1edad891, 0xce6279cf, 0xcd3e7e6f,
                0x1618b166, 0xfd2c1d05, 0x848fd2c5, 0xf6fb2299, 0xf523f357, 0xa6327623,
                0x93a83531, 0x56cccd02, 0xacf08162, 0x5a75ebb5, 0x6e163697, 0x88d273cc,
                0xde966292, 0x81b949d0, 0x4c50901b, 0x71c65614, 0xe6c6c7bd, 0x327a140a,
                0x45e1d006, 0xc3f27b9a, 0xc9aa53fd, 0x62a80f00, 0xbb25bfe2, 0x35bdd2f6,
                0x71126905, 0xb2040222, 0xb6cbcf7c, 0xcd769c2b, 0x53113ec0, 0x1640e3d3,
                0x38abbd60, 0x2547adf0, 0xba38209c, 0xf746ce76, 0x77afa1c5, 0x20756060,
                0x85cbfe4e, 0x8ae88dd8, 0x7aaaf9b0, 0x4cf9aa7e, 0x1948c25c, 0x02fb8a8c,
                0x01c36ae4, 0xd6ebe1f9, 0x90d4f869, 0xa65cdea0, 0x3f09252d, 0xc208e69f,
                0xb74e6132, 0xce77e25b, 0x578fdfe3, 0x3ac372e6
            }
        };

        uint[] P;
        uint[,] S;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs and initializes a blowfish instance with the supplied key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key to cipher with.</param>
        public Blowfish(byte[] key)
        {
            short i;
            short j;
            short k;
            uint data;
            uint datal;
            uint datar;

            P = _P.Clone() as uint[];
            S = _S.Clone() as uint[,];

            j = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < N + 2; ++i)
            {
                data = 0x00000000;
                for (k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
                {
                    data = (data << 8) | key[j];
                    j++;
                    if (j >= key.Length)
                    {
                        j = 0;
                    }
                }
                P[i] = P[i] ^ data;
            }

            datal = 0x00000000;
            datar = 0x00000000;

            for (i = 0; i < N + 2; i += 2)
            {
                Encipher(ref datal, ref datar);
                P[i] = datal;
                P[i + 1] = datar;
            }

            for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 256; j += 2)
                {
                    Encipher(ref datal, ref datar);

                    S[i, j] = datal;
                    S[i, j + 1] = datar;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private uint F(uint x)
        {
            ushort a;
            ushort b;
            ushort c;
            ushort d;
            uint y;

            d = (ushort)(x & 0x00FF);
            x >>= 8;
            c = (ushort)(x & 0x00FF);
            x >>= 8;
            b = (ushort)(x & 0x00FF);
            x >>= 8;
            a = (ushort)(x & 0x00FF);
            //y = ((S[0][a] + S[1][b]) ^ S[2][c]) + S[3][d];
            y = S[0, a] + S[1, b];
            y = y ^ S[2, c];
            y = y + S[3, d];

            return y;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypts a byte array in place.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">The array to encrypt.</param>
        /// <param name="length">The amount to encrypt.</param>
        public void Encipher(byte[] data, int length)
        {
            uint xl, xr;
            if ((length % 8) != 0)
                throw new Exception("Invalid Length");
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 8)
            {
                // Encode the data in 8 byte blocks.
                xl = (uint)((data[i] << 24) | (data[i + 1] << 16) | (data[i + 2] << 8) | data[i + 3]);
                xr = (uint)((data[i + 4] << 24) | (data[i + 5] << 16) | (data[i + 6] << 8) | data[i + 7]);
                Encipher(ref xl, ref xr);
                // Now Replace the data.
                data[i] = (byte)(xl >> 24);
                data[i + 1] = (byte)(xl >> 16);
                data[i + 2] = (byte)(xl >> 8);
                data[i + 3] = (byte)(xl);
                data[i + 4] = (byte)(xr >> 24);
                data[i + 5] = (byte)(xr >> 16);
                data[i + 6] = (byte)(xr >> 8);
                data[i + 7] = (byte)(xr);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypts 8 bytes of data (1 block)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xl">The left part of the 8 bytes.</param>
        /// <param name="xr">The right part of the 8 bytes.</param>
        private void Encipher(ref uint xl, ref uint xr)
        {
            uint Xl;
            uint Xr;
            uint temp;
            short i;

            Xl = xl;
            Xr = xr;

            for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                Xl = Xl ^ P[i];
                Xr = F(Xl) ^ Xr;

                temp = Xl;
                Xl = Xr;
                Xr = temp;
            }

            temp = Xl;
            Xl = Xr;
            Xr = temp;

            Xr = Xr ^ P[N];
            Xl = Xl ^ P[N + 1];

            xl = Xl;
            xr = Xr;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypts a byte array in place.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">The array to decrypt.</param>
        /// <param name="length">The amount to decrypt.</param>
        public void Decipher(byte[] data, int length)
        {
            uint xl, xr;
            if ((length % 8) != 0)
                throw new Exception("Invalid Length");
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 8)
            {
                // Encode the data in 8 byte blocks.
                xl = (uint)((data[i] << 24) | (data[i + 1] << 16) | (data[i + 2] << 8) | data[i + 3]);
                xr = (uint)((data[i + 4] << 24) | (data[i + 5] << 16) | (data[i + 6] << 8) | data[i + 7]);
                Decipher(ref xl, ref xr);
                // Now Replace the data.
                data[i] = (byte)(xl >> 24);
                data[i + 1] = (byte)(xl >> 16);
                data[i + 2] = (byte)(xl >> 8);
                data[i + 3] = (byte)(xl);
                data[i + 4] = (byte)(xr >> 24);
                data[i + 5] = (byte)(xr >> 16);
                data[i + 6] = (byte)(xr >> 8);
                data[i + 7] = (byte)(xr);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypts 8 bytes of data (1 block)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xl">The left part of the 8 bytes.</param>
        /// <param name="xr">The right part of the 8 bytes.</param>
        private void Decipher(ref uint xl, ref uint xr)
        {
            uint Xl;
            uint Xr;
            uint temp;
            short i;

            Xl = xl;
            Xr = xr;

            for (i = N + 1; i > 1; --i)
            {
                Xl = Xl ^ P[i];
                Xr = F(Xl) ^ Xr;

                /* Exchange Xl and Xr */
                temp = Xl;
                Xl = Xr;
                Xr = temp;
            }

            /* Exchange Xl and Xr */
            temp = Xl;
            Xl = Xr;
            Xr = temp;

            Xr = Xr ^ P[1];
            Xl = Xl ^ P[0];

            xl = Xl;
            xr = Xr;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As a first step you could try looking at the public methods on the classes and see which ones seem to  fit what you're trying to do then post again if you get stuck :)

Comment: Short of describing the syntax for C# itself, there really is nothing that an answer here could add, which isn't already described quite adequately by the comments for `Blowfish()` and `Encipher()`. Did you read them? What code have you tried and what error(s) did you get? Is this homework by any chance?

Comment: I posted above, as I call and what error I get

Comment: The question title should be changed to "problems understanding an open source Blowfish API" or something like that. There are in fact no problems at all when starting the class, it just does what it was instructed to do.

Comment: You've changed your original question and you're now asking at least 2 more distinct questions. If you want people to help you then try posting them as separate questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You called the "Encipher" method, asking it to encrypt the first 8 bytes of "data". And that's just what it did. No problem there.

2) If you ask it to encrypt the first 64 bytes of "data", it fails because the data is shorter than 64 bytes. No problem there either.

3) The product of Blowfish encryption is an array of bytes that can't really be displayed by  treating it as ASCII text because it contains all kinds of non-displayable and non-7bit characters. ASCIIEncoding replaces these with a question mark character.

Comment: To display the characters you should use a character set that covers at least one complete byte (8 bits, i.e. values from 0 to 255). ASCII is 7-bit ASCII (i.e. values from 0 9 127). To see the changes use UTF8 or Default for example.

Comment: @Obalix - even UTF8 or Default would have a hard time displaying characters in the 0-31 range. Additionally, a random byte-array like this would almost certainly not be a valid UTF-8 data. A better approach would be to use BitConverter.ToString(data) instead of trying to treat it as ASCII or other text.

Comment: and another question, it turns out that I can encrypt a string, which is a multiple of 8?
ie lines are equal to the length of 8, 16, 24 and so on.
but what if the string is equal to 17 or 34?

Comment: is the last questions that I want an answer, especially in the second. Help please

Comment: I know how to solve the problem when the string length is not a multiple of 8
for this will need to fill the remainder of the string with spaces to the size of which will be multiple of 8

Comment: remains to understand why message: ololoololoololoololoololoololoololoololoololoololoololoololoaaas key: 1234567812345678 and i get result: D2-11-FB-49-D6-93-F8-F5-BC-34-75-B2-EC-69-34-A0-2D-09-51-A0-52-BE-4F-F4-25-D7-DF-F0-49-2F-C5-02-09-9B-99-64-53-D8-A0-08-D2-11-FB-49-D6-93-F8-F5-BC-34-75-B2-EC-69-34-A0-A0-74-81-2C-17-E7-E1-9E but i must have result: d211fb49d693f8f5bc3475b2ec6934a02d0951a052be4ff425d7dff0492fc502099b996453d8a008d211fb49d693f8f5bc3475b2ec6934a0a074812c17e7e19e

Comment: Isn't it apparent that all you have to do now is to remove all '-' characters and convert the string to lowercase? Try BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant() and see what you get.

Comment: The size has to be a multiple of 8 because Blowfish works with 8-byte blocks. Also, be aware that you are using Blowfish in ECB mode which is very unsecure - recommended reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation

Comment: Many thanks, mr.Lukas Pokorny to the account of the comments on the ecb. I see what's what with the principle of the class, I admire the algorithm description and try to make adjustments

Comment: I beg your pardon, I'm just here for the first time. I will now try to recover all their questions

Comment: @Alex, no problem, I'm a newbie as well. Just try reading the FAQ first: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I have laid out immediately ready version which encode text. I think it will be useful for people who stumble upon this subject, they immediately get a working example. could you tell me at the expense of decoding. Why not decrypt correctly?

Comment: @Alex, the problem with entirely changing the original question is that it makes all the replies to the original question look like nonsense. When someone correctly answers your question, you are supposed to accept their answer. It's fine if you want to ask more questions then - but post them separately.

Comment: @Alex, it looks like the content of "dec" is broken. Looks like you still used ASCIIEncoding or the like to produce it.